# Understanding a complex query in pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting

I am new to pgrouting and basically am familier with `sql` and `postgresql`, i came across the following command below:

```sql
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                30, 60, false, false);
```

I am used to seeing sql statements as below:

```sql
SELECT param1 , param2
```

But i am thrown off the hook when i see something like:

```sql
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge
```

What's with the `AS` part ?

Also is the below a subquery ?? and can somebody explain it ? I am not very clear with the below query.

```sql
(' SELECT gid AS id,
         source::integer,
         target::integer,
         length::double precision AS cost
        FROM ways',
30, 60, false, false);
```

Got the above query from **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#shortest-path-dijkstra)**.

Answer (score 2):

```
column_name AS some_new_name
```

is standard aliasing in SQL.

Many of the pgRouting functions expect as part of input, a query that defines the set of edges you want to consider for routing.  These edges need to have a query that outputs at least the following column names:  id, source, target, and cost (thus the need for the AS cost).  For cases where you consider rerverse direction of travel, you also need a reverse_cost column.  You can have more columns, but need at least those.

So that is what you see with this query:

```
'SELECT gid AS id,
     source::integer,
     target::integer,
     length::double precision AS cost
    FROM ways'
```

The pgr_dijkstra function returns a set of rows with columns id1, id2, cost  (this changes in pgRouting 2.1 with new syntax by the way so they are more meaningfully called node, edge.   So the AS you see at the top:

```
    SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
```

Is to give the output columns more real world meaning.

I should add the source::integer, target::integer was required in pgRouting 2.0 calling syntax to cast things like bigint columns to integer, since bigints weren't supported in 2.0.  This changes in 2.1 as well so that casting would no longer be needed.

Refer to the dev docs to see what I'm talking about: http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/dijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-dijkstra

Comment: is `'SELECT gid AS id,
     source::integer,
     target::integer,
     length::double precision AS cost
    FROM ways'` a subquery ??

Comment: It can be.  In this case it's selecting the whole table.  If you had a huge table, you'd probably filter it a bit to just include a range box around your start and end nodes guaranteeing all roads that should be considered are..  Anyway as you can see, it is a string and pgr_dijikstra internally does a dynamic query execute.

Comment: The important thing to understand is that pgr_dijkstra is a set returning function.  So do this: SELECT pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                30, 60, false, false);  The when you put it in the FROM and do * , or explicitly specify the columns it explodes the row columns of each record